# Trouble loading Ubuntu 18.04.2 on new SSD

Tags: grub2

I successfully installed to a new SDD via a USB installer, but grub install failed every time I tried, and I had to install it manually. I managed to figure out that the linux "/" dir was at /dev/sdc2 and configure my BIOS to use the right hard drive on boot, but it always puts me in the GRUB command line on startup. I have to type:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sdc2 ro
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Then my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS installation boots properly. What do I need to do so that GRUB gives me a menu of kernel version options--or even better, just starts up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), it will definitely solve the issue.
This will reinstall GRUB and add all other OS on the disk.

Comment: Please do not just post links to soluitons, try to highlight the main ideas from the link while also supplying the link

Comment: What did it do to solve the problem? It worked but I'm no wiser for it.

Comment: It will reinstall the grub